# D3 scatterplot hot to manage domain and range properly?

Tags: d3.js, scatter-plot

i'm building a scatterplot
https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/QWgGMja

i couldn't make Y axis show format in xx : xx< but i dont understand why X-axis showing years like this. Pls help

https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/bgpXyK - this is how it is suppose to look

```
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                      .domain([ d3.min(years), d3.max(years)  ])
                      .range([paddings.paddingLeft,w - paddings.paddingRight]);
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
      svg.append("g")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - paddings.paddingLeft) + ")")
                      .attr("id","x-axis")
                      .call(xAxis);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to make use of the tickformat function

 like this:`var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.format('d'));`

here it is placed in your given code snippet:

```js
      const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                      .domain([ d3.min(years), d3.max(years)  ])
                      .range([paddings.paddingLeft,w - paddings.paddingRight]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.format('d'));
      svg.append("g")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - paddings.paddingLeft) + ")")
                      .attr("id","x-axis")
                      .call(xAxis);
```

This should fix your problem with the the years not displaying as intended on the X-axis.

Here is a link with further information on tickformat: https://github.com/d3/d3-axis

Comment: oh.wow.it did. Thank you very much. however i screwed somewhere else. cuz dots are not matching scales i'm so noob https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/QWgGMja